# I cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5, I'm having an issue while adding a column to a table

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`homest
>     ead`.`#sql-4f4_a9`, CONSTRAINT `posts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQ
>     L: alter table `posts` add constraint posts_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade
>     )

Comment: can you post here the method raising this error (where you update your model)

Comment: Yes, let's see your code please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work for you. I tested it in my own setup.

Make sure the posts table is deleted from your database before running this migration. Otherwise it may fail.

If it's not deleted by reversing the migration you could delete it manualy. If you do so don't forget to delete the rule from the migrations table in your database.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class ToPostTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->timestamp('published_at');   
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); 
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('posts');
    }

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80211/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-snijder-i-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-fore).

Comment: @bluefeet, Thank you for pointing out the chat rooms. I didn't know about those.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have `user_id` in the `fillable` property of your Post model.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Really? Why is that?